# jsdelivr doesn't update github commits

Tags: javascript, github, commit, cdn

I have a js file stored here in [GitHub](https://github.com/JaPatGitHub/EduSimulations/blob/main/Tools/x-y-coordinate%20pointer.js).

```js
    // Define the function before setup() i.e. at the top if defining in same js file
    // Call the function under draw()
    function pointCoord() {
      stroke(255,0,0);
      line(mouseX,0, mouseX, height);
      line(0,mouseY, width, mouseY);
      if (mouseIsPressed){console.log(`x = ${mouseX}, y = ${mouseY}`);}
      }
```

This is its jsdelivr link: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/JaPatGitHub/EduSimulations@main/Tools/x-y-coordinate%20pointer.js

```js
// Define the function before setup() i.e. at the top if defining in same js file
// Call the function under draw()
function pointCoord() {
  stroke(255,0,0);
  line(mouseX,0, mouseX, height);
  line(0,mouseY, width, mouseY);
  if (mouseIsPressed){print("x = "+ mouseX+ ", y = "+mouseY);}
  }
```

(If you are curious this doesn't look like Vanilla JS code..this file is meant to be used under the [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) library)

As you would see, the last line on both pages is different. Actually, the jsdelivr page doesn't show the content updated with the previous 2 commits on GitHub - and it's over 10 hours since I have committed them.

Now how do I update the code in jsdelivr CDN?

Comment: Pretty in-depth answer to this question in [a jsdelivr issue opened on Github](https://github.com/jsdelivr/jsdelivr/issues/18417#issuecomment-1163078689): "_If you use a @main reference the releases are not relevant at all and it follows the branch caching behavior. If you used @latest the release caching behavior would apply (note that it's "up to 7", not "strictly 7" in that case)_" and `@latest` currently takes up to 12 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jsDelivr's website regarding [GitHub CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/features)

> We use a permanent S3 storage to ensure all files remain available even if GitHub goes down, or a repository or a release is deleted by its author. **Files are fetched directly from GitHub only the first time, or when S3 goes down**.

Use a release (or some other named) branch and then access that branch from jsDelivr.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following link to retrieve the latest version of your code from jsDelivr:
**https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/JaPatGitHub/EduSimulations@latest/Tools/x-y-coordinate%20pointer.js**

By using **@latest** in the link, you're instructing jsDelivr to serve the most recent version available in the repository, regardless of the branch name.

Comment: You just _Selvad_ me, truly appreciated for showing this **latest** gem.